# Methods to see result fo a code change faster

Tags: java, eclipse, jakarta-ee, jboss

This question came to me when developing using Eclipse.

I use JBoss Application Server and use hot code replacement. But this option requires that the 'build automatically' option to be enabled. This makes Eclipse build the workspace automatically (periodically or when a file is saved?) and for a large code base this takes too much time and processing which makes the machine freeze for a while. Also sometimes an error message is shown saying that hot code replacement failed.

The question that I have is: is there a better way to see the result of a code change?

---

Currently I have the following two suggestions:

1. Have unit tests - this will allow to run a single test and see the result of a code change. ( But for a JavaEE application that uses EJBs is it easy to setup unit tests?)
2. Use OSGi - which allows to add jars to the running system without bringing down the JVM.

Any ideas on above suggestions or any other suggestion or a framework that allows to do this is welcome.

Comment: `build automatically` will cause a build whenever a file is saved.

Comment: @edthethird wrong, build automatically should only trigger compilation for the single class that was changed, and in debug session it will trigger Hotswap which will work if class schema wasn't changed

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Did you take a look at http://zeroturnaround.com/jrebel/?

Answer (score 1):

I tell you how I work. I hope it is useful. First of all, I disable "Build Automatically". Maybe it is better if you do a simple ANT script to compile and see errors/exceptions. Also, I make jar file with the same script. Afterwards, I use OSGi to check the application. Yo do not need to stop server, only you need to change versions in deployed bundles. Intead of JBoss Server I use Equinox which includes Jetty Web Server.

May you have a nice day!

Comment: Thanks for the answer. When you say switch versions in the deployed bundles, do you do it manually or does the IDE ( Eclipse or any other ) support this?

Comment: I do it by changing version number in MANIFEST.MF file

Answer (score 0):

With [JRebel](http://zeroturnaround.com/jrebel), you wouldn't have to build your project (skip the build totally). Plus, only the changed resources will be reloaded so the update happens instantly. Plus, session is preserved so you do not have re-login to the application after the update was performed.

Answer (score 0):

Even though the question I asked was quite specific to Java, I thought that mentioning using an interpreted programming language that avoids the compilation step is anther way of seeing result of a code change faster.